# Bond length in square planar coordination complex of Platinum

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

(Q): Select the correct statements for $[Pt(NH_3)_2Cl_2]$ :

(a): Geometrical Isomerism

(b): Optical Isomerism

(c): All bond length are equal.

(d): Chelation effect is effect.

(e): Hydrogen bonding is present.

Pt is in +2 oxidation state in this compound. I know that that for 4d and 5d series transition metals, most ligands behave as Strong field ligands for them. Therefore the structure of this would a low spin, inner orbital complex or we can say a square planar structure is formed. Since it is of the type $[MA_2B_2]$. It will show cis trans geometrical isomerism. Hence option (a) turns out to be correct. Since it is square planar, it will show no optical isomerism. No chelation effect is present as there are no chelating ligands. Both amine and chlorido are monodentate. No hydrogen bonding is also present. The option I am struggling with is option (c). I know that bond lengths in square planar are equal only when the ligands are same. Here the ligands are not same and hence the  bond lengths are not equal. I want to know exactly which bonds are shorter and which longer and why. I have tried to search for it but could not find it. I need help here.

Comment: N and Cl: which is bigger?

Answer (score 1):

The bond lengths in cisplatin are:
Pt-Cl: 2.298 Å to 2.325 Å
Pt-NH3: 2.04 Å
so clearly Pt-Cl bonds are longer
This maybe due to small size of Ammonia molecule which enables it to come closer to the central metal atom